# Android save user session

Tags: android, session, zend-framework, authentication, zend-auth

I'm new in android I'm trying to save login session and send it with every time I send request to server, My web service is PHP (Zend framework 2).

This code to identify user:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$IdentityObj = $auth->getIdentity();
```

It's possible save session and send it like I use web browser without make any change in my web service.

Comment: of course it's possible. I recently worked on OpenCart (i'm not sure which framework it's using). You can get session. store it in share preferences and then retrieve it when you want to send a request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. You just have to store the session using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

The idea is, after you login, I guess you return some kind of session id or whatever. You just need to store it. Then, in subsequents executions, you just fetch that session before doing any request.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
    getSharedPreferences("com.blabla.yourapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Save it
preferences.edit().putString("session", <yoursessiontoken>).commit();

//Fetch it
// The second parameter is the default value.
preferences.getString("session", "");
```

Anyway is better that you read the documentation to really understand what you are doing.

Comment: but what about when i clear Cache of application. Preferences are also clear.

Comment: Clearing the app cache doesn't clear the preferences.

Answer (score 7):

Using `SharedPreferences` is a way to save and retrieve key, value pair data in Android and also to keep session all throughout the entire application.

To work with `SharedPreferences` you to take the following steps:

1. Initialization of the share `SharedPreferences` interface by passing two arguments to the constructor (String and integer)

   ```
   // Sharedpref file name
   private static final String PREF_NAME = "PreName";
   // Shared pref mode
   int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
   //Initialising the SharedPreferences
   SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
           .getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
   ```
2. Using Editor interface and its methods to modify the SharedPreferences values and for storing data for future retrieval

   ```
   //Initialising the Editor
   Editor editor = pref.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
   editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
   editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
   editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
   editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long     
   editor.commit(); // commit changes
   ```
3. Retrieving Data:

   Data can be retrieved from saved preferences by calling `getString()` (For string) method. Remember this method should be called on Shared Preferences not on Editor.

   ```
   // returns stored preference value
   // If value is not present return second param value - In this case null
   pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
   pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
   pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
   pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
   pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
   ```
4. **Finally, Clearing / Deleting Data like in the case of logout**

   If you want to delete from shared preferences you can call `remove(“key_name”)` to delete that particular value. If you want to delete all the data, call `clear()`

   ```
   editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
   editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email

   editor.commit(); // commit changes

   //Following will clear all the data from shared preferences
   editor.clear();
   editor.commit(); // commit changes
   ```

If you wish, follow this link to download a simple and straightforward example: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Also, this is the implementation class I use:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;
    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;
    // Context
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";
    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    // Constructor
    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     */
    public void createLoginSession(String name, String email) {
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status If false it will redirect
     * user to login page Else won't do anything
     */
    public void checkLogin() {
        // Check login status
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get stored session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

Finally, you will have to create an instance of this `SessionManager` class in the `onCreate` method of your activity class and then call the `createLoginSession` for the session that will be used throughout the entire app

```
// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.createLoginSession("Username", intentValue);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Better than the chosen answer