# Google OAuth - Where to Store Client ID

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I followed this link to allow my users to authenticate via google:
https://dev.to/jorgecf/integrating-google-authentication-with-your-angular-app-4j2a

However, I have to have my Google Client ID in my UI code:

```
return pload.then(async () => {
  await gapi.auth2
    .init({ client_id: 'abc123' })  // Put my client ID here. How should I store this?
    .then(auth => {
      this.gapiSetup = true;
      this.authInstance = auth;
    });
});
```

Is that a security issue? If so, where/how would I store that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Straight to the point

You could store it anywhere in your web, usually using javascript.

## Detailed explanation

I received similar questions so  I think is a valid question.

Oauth2 flow needs the client_id int the browser, so is not a security issue.

Why? : Because that's how it's defined the **OAUTH2 SPECIFICATION**

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

## Why client_id is required?

Your angular code needs the client_id to generate the **auth url** and then perform a redirection to that url. No matter the oauth2 provider (google, facebook, etc), that url has the following syntax:

```
https://auth.acme.com/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://myweb.com/callback&client_id=******
```

> Note **redirect_uri** and **client_id** fields.

This **auth url** is responsible to redirect the user to the login form (google, facebook, microsoft, etc), then receive the credentials and perform the redirection (back to your web) to **redirect_uri** sending the **code** value

This flow is called Oauth2 Authorization Code Flow/Grant. More details here: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow

## What would be an issue?

To have the secret in your frontend(angular) would be the security issue.

The client_secret and client_id with another fields are required to retrieve the access_token in your case from google. This token will allow you to consume apis (drive, map, etc) if you have the correct permissions.

**This exchange must be in your backend** not in the frontend!!

More details here about how to get the access_token using client_di, client_secret and auth_code

https://help.akana.com/content/current/cm/api_oauth/oauth_oauth20/m_oauth20_getTokenPOST.htm

## How partial hide it?

Create the **auth url** in your backend and return it to your frontend with a 302 http code. Browser will perform a instantaneous redirection.

I said partial, because a curious buddy could stop the redirection (esc key) or use the browser console and view your **auth url** which contains the **client_id** field

## Where to store the client_id ?

Finally, if you understood that the visibility of client_id is not a problem, you could store anywhere in your frontend:

- Global javascript variable (before SPA transpilation)
- Html templating (SSR)

Finally you will need the full auth url (once during the user session), not only the client_id. So instead to build the auth url in the frontend, you could create it somewhere in your backend and then retrieve it in the frontend. Sample

GET `/v1/authorize/url`

## Where to store the access_token ?

Similar case of client_id. We can store it anywhere in the web. Due this value will be required constantly to consume the web services, rest api or microservices, usually is stored in:

- Javascript Local Storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage
- Javascript global variable
- Angular : Add it dynamically to `src/environment/environment.ts` or as inner variable of Service using dependency injection
- React/Angular Store

And same apply to the mobiles:

- Android SharedPreferences: [Android save user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720313/android-save-user-session)

Feel free to use this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215054/oauth2-budy to ask another questions related to oauth2

Answer (score 1):

The option I've always used is to deploy a configuration file with your web static content, and include **Public Open Id Connect Settings** in it.

Here is an [example configuration file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/spa.config.json) from a code sample of mine. Of course, there is no way anyone can get tokens based on this information - you need valid credentials in addition.

Often components such as UIs and APIs are pushed down a pipeline:

- DEV
- QA
- STAGING
- PRODUCTION

Your continuous delivery process can deal with delivering different settings to each stage of the pipeline. Your code is then clean and never includes any hard coded values.