# Google Auth User Cryptic Properties

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I'm using google auth on a web project and I'm trying to understand the property names. The screenshot shows the `user` object returned by google. I can access the `id_token` this way:

```
this.user.Zb.id_token
```

Why `Zb`? A year ago it was this:

```
this.user.wc.id_token
```

Notice it was `wc` back then and now my UI code breaks. What am I missing? Why are those property names used? How do I make it so I can access `id_token` regardless of its parent property name?

[image]

This is the UI code:

```
  async authenticate(): Promise<gapi.auth2.GoogleUser> {
    // Initialize gapi if not done yet
    if (!this.gapiSetup) {
      await this.initGoogleAuth();
    }

    // Resolve or reject signin Promise
    return new Promise(async () => {
      await this.authInstance.signIn().then(
        user => {
          this.user = user;
          console.log('this.user: ', this.user);
          
          this.cookieService.set('jwt', this.user.Zb.id_token, 365); // expires in one year (365 days)
          // this.cookieService.set('jwt', this.user.wc.id_token, 365); // expires in one year (365 days)

          this.owlerApiService.getHooterUsingIdTokenFromProvider()
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
              this.userDto = data;            
            },
            error => {
              console.log('error: ', error);
            });
        },
        error => this.error = error);
    });
  }

  async initGoogleAuth(): Promise<void> {
    // Create a new Promise where the resolve function is the callback passed to gapi.load
    const pload = new Promise((resolve) => {
      gapi.load('auth2', resolve);
    });

    // When the first promise resolves, it means we have gapi loaded and that we can call gapi.init
    return pload.then(async () => {
      // ClientId safe to put here? Looks like it:
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123945/279516
      await gapi.auth2
        .init({ client_id: 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com' })
        .then(auth => {
          this.gapiSetup = true;
          this.authInstance = auth;
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I can’t find a reference to this property anywhere in the Google JavaScript SDK documentation; can you elaborate on where you got the understanding you should be accessing the `id_token` this way?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I just logged the return value from google and looked until I found `id_token`. It happened to be within a property called `wc`, so I just referenced it there. It worked just fine, but now, a year later, the `wc` property is `Zb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t believe you’re using the SDK in its intended form; it’s not clear to me how you determined that this is the proper way to access the `id_token` value for the authenticated user as it’s not mentioned anywhere in the official docs.

[`signIn()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsignin) returns an instance of `GoogleUser`, on which you can call [`getAuthResponse()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetauthresponseincludeauthorizationdata). The returned [`gapi.auth2.AuthResponse` object](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authresponse) includes the `id_token`:

```
await this.authInstance.signIn().then(
    user => {
      this.user = user;
      console.log('this.user: ', this.user);
      
      this.cookieService.set('jwt', this.user.getAuthResponse().id_token, 365); // expires in one year (365 days)
      // …
```

Comment: Oh, wow, so I had to call a method on the returned object to get what I need. Let me try that...

Comment: That worked. Thank you!